# XSL: why doesn't output indent work?

Tags: xml, xslt

This is my XSL spreadsheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="outer">
               <xsl:apply-templates select="elements"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="element1">
       <xsl:element name="output1">
            <xsl:element name="output1.5" />
       </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template match="element2">
       <xsl:element name="output2"/>
    </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>

<elements>
    <element1>value1</element1>
    <element2>value2</element2>
</elements>
```

The output is not indented according to the output XML hierarchy. This is the actual output (note how output1.5 and output1 are not indented properly):

```
<outer>
    <output1>
<output1.5/>
</output1>
    <output2/>
</outer>
```

Comment: You must be using a buggy XSLT 2.0 processor. With all XSLT 2.0 processors I have: Saxon 9.1.05, Saxon 9.4.06EE, XQSharp (XmlPrime) and Altova 2012 I get indented results

Comment: Which XSLT 2.0 processor do you use? How do you run the transformation, how do you save the result and look at it?

Comment: I'm using javax.xml.transform to run the transformation, with all default configs. How can I check which processor this Java library uses?

Comment: As far as I know the XSLT processor provided by the Sun or Oracle JRE and JDK is an XSLT 1.0 processor based on Apache Xalan.

Answer (score 6):

What you're seeing is actually the result of not indenting at all; the two lines that ARE indented are a result of processing the white space used to indent the source document.

If you were to add `<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />` to your stylesheet, you'd get no indentation at all in your output.

Indentation isn't actually controlled by the XSLT processor, it's controlled by whatever serializes the output to a string, although this is generally done by the same method call. I can't say for sure why the `xsl:output` instruction didn't do the job, but you can add this to your java:

```
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
```

And optionally, if you want to set how much to indent by:

```
transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");
```

I can't say for sure, but it's entirely possible the problem is that the amount to indent by isn't being set, and is using 0.

Comment: Worked for me using groovy.

Comment: I got it to work setting the amount using 
`<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" xalan:indent-amount="4"/>` and added an `xmlns:xalan="xml.apache.org/xalan"` to the outermost xsl: tag.